# Is there really no way to integrate $e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Today in my calculus class, we encountered the function $e^{-x^2}$, and I was told that it was not integrable.

I was very surprised. Is there really **no way** to find the integral of $e^{-x^2}$? Graphing $e^{-x^2}$, it appears as though it should be.

A [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) on Gaussian Functions states that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$

This is from -infinity to infinity. If the function can be integrated within these bounds, I'm unsure why it can't be integrated with respect to $(a, b)$.

Is there really no way to find the integral of $e^{-x^2}$, or are the methods to finding it found in branches higher than second semester calculus?

Comment: There is no antiderivative written in _elementary_ functions (imagine the roots for a polynomial of degree, e.g., five, for which there is no formula).

Comment: There is no *elementary function* whose derivative is $e^{-x^2}$. By elementary function we mean something obtained using arithmetical operations and composition from the standard functions we all know and love. But this is not a serious problem.  A few important *definite integrals* involving $e^{-x^2}$ have pleasant closed form.

Comment: Try reading [this note](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf) of Brian Conrad's and the article by Rosenlicht referenced therein.

Comment: I guess this is not really a duplicate of [How to integrate $\int e^{-t^2} dt$ using introductory calculus methods](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138664/856)?

Comment: Well, in someway it is no more surprising than stating that $\frac{1}{2}$ cannot be written as an integer. As noted by others, it is integrable, it is just that the collection of 'standard' functions is not rich enough to express the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there are three or four different meanings being given to the word "integrable" here:

  (1) $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on intervals $[a,b]$ (yes, every continuous function is)

  (2) $f(x)$ has an antiderivative that is an elementary function (no, it doesn't: the antiderivative $\sqrt{\pi}\  \text{erf}(x)/2$ is not an elementary function)

  (3) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\ dx < \infty$ (yes, and this is the usual meaning of "integrable" in analysis)

  (4) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx$ can be expressed in "closed form" (yes, it is $\sqrt{\pi}$).

Comment: Sure, just use polar coordinates. That's what Gauss did.

Comment: you can use a trick to say that it = I and find $I^{2}$ then square  root it to find a form over any bound for the function

Comment: Try [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWOGfzC3IeY) if you guys are still unable to solve it.

Comment: Hi Vivek, welcome to Math.SE.  We prefer not to have answers that just consist of a link with no further explanation.  Also, this video is about the definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$, which is not really what the question is about (the asker already knows about this case).

Comment: the video is legitimate (its title is "Integral of exp(-x^2) | MIT 18.02SC Multivariable Calculus, Fall 2010"), but it would have been better if you explained in the answer what it is.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Integration does produce new kinds  of functions. Consider $\ln x=\int_1^x (1/y)\;dy$ for $y>0$, which cannot be expressed in terms of arithmetic  combinations,  even allowing constant non-integer powers, of rational functions.

Comment: I recently wondered why using a series representation cannot get $\sqrt{\pi}$, when its interval of convergence is infinity.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

That function is integrable. As a matter of fact, any continuous function (on a compact interval) is Riemann integrable (it doesn't even actually have to be continuous, but continuity is enough to guarantee integrability on a compact interval). The antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ (up to a constant factor) is called the error function, and can't be written in terms of the simple functions you know from calculus, but that is all.

Comment: But the evaluation of the integral over the whole real line is relatively easy!

Comment: Easy for Lord Kelvin.

Comment: You probably mean that any continuous function is Riemann integrable on a compact interval.

Comment: How to show that the function is non-elementary? I cannot remember seeing a proof of that.

Comment: @M.B.: see for example M.P. Wiener's text [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative/265884#265884).

Comment: Why don't you show us what it looks like?

Answer (score 88):

To build on kee wen's answer and provide more readability, here is an analytic method of obtaining a definite integral for the Gaussian function over the entire real line:

Let $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$.

Then,
$$\begin{align}
I^2 &= \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\right) \times \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}dy\right) \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx\right)dy \\
\end{align}$$

Next we change to polar form: $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $dx\,dy=dA=r\,d\theta\,dr$. Therefore

$$\begin{align}
I^2 &= \iint e^{-(r^2)}r\,d\theta\,dr \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}dr\right)d\theta \\
&=2\pi\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}dr
\end{align}$$

Next, let's change variables so that $u=r^2$, $du=2r\,dr$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
2I^2 &=2\pi\int_{r=0}^\infty 2re^{-r^2}dr \\
&= 2\pi \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u} du \\
&= 2\pi \left(-e^{-\infty}+e^0\right) \\
&= 2\pi \left(-0+1\right) \\
&= 2\pi
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $I=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Just bear in mind that this is simpler than obtaining a definite integral of the Gaussian over some interval (a,b), and we still cannot obtain an antiderivative for the Gaussian expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: If $e^{-x^2}$ is the area under the curve then $I^2$ should have units of $area^{2}$. But \begin{align}
I^2 &= \iint e^{-(r^2)}r\,d\theta\,dr \\
\end{align} has units of volume. How is it possible?

Comment: @user599310 The units of $I^2$ are indeed units of $area^2$, but so too are the units of $\iint e^{-(r^2)}r\,d\theta\,dr$ in $area^2$.

First note that $dA = r\,d\theta\,dr = dx\,dy$, all of which are in units of $area$. Second note that $e^{-r^2}$ is equivalent to $e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$. In words, the base shift that we performed from $dx\,dy$ to $r\,d\theta\,dr$ changes us from measuring the function in terms of two lengths, to measuring it in terms of chunks of areas. Hence why $e^{-r^2}$ is a function that returns areas, where $e^{-x^2}$ returns lengths.

Comment: @CopaceticMan What I don't understand is if we plot the function $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ then shouldn't the integral give us back the volume under the surface?

Comment: @user599310, I am going to attempt some pseudo math to show it:

$$ I^2 = \int e^-x^2 dx \times \int e^-x^2 dx  = Area \times Area = Area^2$$

We can replace one x, with a dummy variable, move the dummy copy into the first integral to get a double integral.

$$ I^2 = \int \int e^{-x^2-y^2} dA $$

**In context**, the integrand a function that returns two Area, as it is the product of two functions which return a distance, specifically the height above one axis. So $fdA$ is still in terms of $area^2$.
You are correct in your confusion, as the leap may not appear obvious, but it's valid.

Comment: If stuck at the second equality, the integral regarding x is treated as a scalar for the integral regarding y.