# Integral of $b[x]^{l[x]} = p[x]$

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

First year calculus student here - I am not sure where to turn for an answer despite searching and playing with Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab, and (forgive me) I do not know the technical vocabulary for what I am trying to do.

What is the equation which when differentiated with respect to x yields $b[x]^{l[x]} + C = p[x]$ ?  Note these names were chosen based upon the relationship $base^{logarithm} = power$ (where, to be clear, "power" is NOT the exponent: i.e. $$b^l=p $$ $$\equiv log_b[p] = l$$ $$\equiv \sqrt[l]{p} = b$$ .

Knowing the integrals of $a^x$ (constant a) and $x^n$ (constant n) has not proved helpful so far.

More generally, what would the process of finding this be called?  Is it in some sense an "inverse" of implicit differentiation?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks Shaun, didn't even know the name for it.  All a part of learning the professional tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, then for a given $b(x),l(x)$ you are asking for a function $p(x)$ so that $p'(x)=b(x)^{l(x)}$

The answer is, we don't know such expressions in general, in fact, sometimes it is just "impossible" to find an expression for the integral of those functions, for example $e^{-x^2}$ (which is $b(x)^{l(x)}$ for $b(x)=e$ and $l(x)=-x^2$).

check out this question
[Is there really no way to integrate $e^{-x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154968/is-there-really-no-way-to-integrate-e-x2)

Edit: maybe this is a better reference
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function
or this
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-indefinite-integral-of-e-x-2