# Whose derivative is $e^{-x^2}?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Say:

> $f'(x) = e^{-x^2}.$

Then, what is $f(x)$ ?

I ask this because I heard:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\, dx=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Thus curious about $f(x),$ but can't figure out it on my own, though tried.

Comment: We can not get it in the elementary functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there really no way to integrate $e^{-x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154968/is-there-really-no-way-to-integrate-e-x2)

Comment: It is rigorously proved that the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ cannot be expressed in elementary terms. The situation is not so different from that of the square root function where we could not write it as a finite combination of arithmetic operations and had to add it as a new vocabulary to the dictionary of functions.