# Solve $\, \mathrm dy/\, \mathrm dx = e^{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $$\frac{\, \mathrm dy}{\, \mathrm dx}=e^{x^{2}}.$$  i using variable separable method to solve this but after some stage i stuck with the integration of $\int e^{x^{2}}\, \mathrm dx$. i dont know what is the integration of $\int e^{x^{2}}\, \mathrm  dx$.  Please help me out!

Comment: There is no closed form integral of $e^{x^2}$. Are you sure you don't have a typo?

Comment: @Ed: it has a closed form. It's not *elementary*, however.

Comment: Er, yes. Thanks for that correction. I should have been more precise.

Comment: See, for instance, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138664) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155).

Comment: Why in this green earth was this question downvoted?

Comment: @J.M. Maybe someone was on the blue part of Earth.

Comment: @J.M. Honest question: what does *closed form* mean if not *elementary*?

Comment: @Rahul: I wrote [a long-ish answer to that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9203) many moons ago, but the gist is, I consider the error function as a "known quantity", and I thus treat it as a closed form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x^{2}}
$$
has no elementary solution. The [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (also called the Gauss error function) is a special function (non-elementary) of sigmoid shape which occurs in probability, statistics and partial differential equations. It is defined as:
$$
    \operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt. 
$$
See the link for reference and more information and thus, J.M. ...?

Comment: ...and thus, the solution of the DE is $y=-\frac{i\sqrt\pi}{2}\mathrm{erf}(ix)+C$. (the *imaginary error function*)