Find solution of the IVP $ y' = y+ \frac12 |\sin(y^2)|,\,\, x>0,\,\, y(0) = -1$

Consider the following initial value problem
$$ y' = y+ \frac12 |\sin(y^2)|,\,\,\,\,\,\, x>0,\,\,\, y(0) = -1$$
Which of the following statements are true?
1.) there exists an $\alpha \in (0,\infty)\,\,$ s.t. $\lim_{x \to \alpha^-}|y(x)| = \infty$ 
2.) y(x) exists on $(0,\infty)\,\,$ and its monotone.
3.) y(x) exists on $(0,\infty)\,\,$ but not bounded below.
4.) y(x) exists on $(0,\infty)\,\,$ but not bounded above.

I thought about using the following inequality
$$\because 0 \le |\sin(y^2)| \le 1\,\,,\forall x$$
Therefore the ODE can be expressed as
$$\because 0 \le y'-y \le \frac12 \,\,,\forall x$$
Post this step I'm not sure how we can proceed further.
Any approach on how to solve this question would help a lot.
Thanks!

multiply by $e^{-x}$ and integrate

But integration would introduce, constant integration wouldn't that interfere with the inequality?

integrate between 0 and x

This question suggest that we still need to add C https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348312/how-does-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-help-to-simplify-difficult-exponent

There is no constant to add when you integrate over a definite interval. You already have the value of $y(0)$.

You have $0 \leqslant y' - y \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$.
Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ yields $0 \leqslant y'(x)e^{-x} - y(x)e^{-x} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$.
Integrating on $[0,x]$, after noticing that $y'(x)e^{-x} - y(x)e^{-x} = (y(x)e^{-x})'$, yields
$$
0 \leqslant
y(x)e^{-x} +1 \leqslant
\frac{1}{2}(1- e^{-x}).
$$
Here, we have used that $y(0)=-1$.
Playing around with the inequalities now gives
$$
-e^x \leqslant y(x) \leqslant -\frac{1}{2}(e^x +1). 
$$
You should be able to conclude now regarding the boundedness of $y$.
For its monotonicity, as pointed out by @HyperbolicPDEfriend, this follows from the fact that $y$ is solution to a first order autonomous ODE.

Notice that you should first justify existence of the solution (Picard-Lindelöf).
Once this is done, the above thing shows that $y$ is bounded on any compact interval of the form $[0,A]$.
Since $y'$ is close to $y$ (from $|y'-y| \leqslant 1/2$), then so is $y'$.
It follows from classical ODE theory that the maximal interval of definition of $y$ cannot be bounded, and thus contains $[0,+\infty)$.

You should check first that the right hand side is locally Lipschitz in $y$. Picard-Lindelöf implies existence and uniqueness.
Under these circumstances, solutions to first order autonomous ODEs (like this one) are always monotone, if the reuqirements for Picard-Lindelöf are met. Further note, that the RHS grows linearly, i.e. in this case
$$
\left \lvert y + \tfrac{1}{2}\lvert \sin(y^2) \rvert \right \rvert \leq \lvert y \rvert + \tfrac{1}{2}\lvert \sin(y^2) \rvert \leq \lvert y \rvert + \tfrac{1}{2}.
$$
In this case, the solution always exists on $\mathbb{R}$.
The solution is bounded from above e.g. by $0$, because $0$ is a solution and cannot be crossed due to uniqueness.
You can show that it is not bounded from below using an ODE comparison principle.
I'm in a rush, but if you need details/sources, let me know.

Sorry, but why solutions to ODEs are always monotone?

To autonomous they are, as far as I know

Do you mean for autonomous first order ODE? This is trivially false for second order ODEs. For first order, I agree (I forgot about this fact, thanks for the reminder)

First order only of course, yes, you are right. And you need to assume that the requirements for Picard-Lindelöf are met, otherwise it is false as well.
